# Authorized_keys not getting permissions or owner set correctly when run from bash script

Tags: permissions, shell, scripting, public-key

With the following snippet of a script to add new users each user gets a public\private key pair automatically created, with the private key in their home directory for winscping out. The script works with one problem: **authorized_keys always gets the owner root, and group root**. Even though I assign the user being added as the owner before and after moving the public key to the authorized_keys file. If I rerun the commands manually after the script everything works fine. I am running the script as root. Permissions also appear to set incorrectly. Any ideas?

```
    usermod -g webteam $UNAME

    cd /home/$UNAME
    ssh-keygen -b 1024 -t dsa -N $UPASS -f $UNAME"key" > key.log
    mkdir .ssh
            chown $UNAME $UNAME"key.pub"
    chgrp $UNAME $UNAME"key.pub"
    mv $UNAME"key.pub" .ssh/authorized_keys
    chmod 740 $UNAME"key"
    chown $UNAME $UNAME"key"

    chown $UNAME .ssh
            echo "PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages" >> .ssh/environment
    chown $UNAME .ssh/*
    chgrp $UNAME .ssh/*
    chmod 700 .ssh/*
    chmod 750 .ssh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you simplify this a bit by just doing a

```
chown -hR $UNAME:webteam /home/$UNAME/.ssh
chmod -R 700 /home/$UNAME/.ssh
```

at the very end?  Assuming `$UNAME` is in fact the username and `webteam` is the right groupname (I'm not sure the `chgrp` you have does what you want).

You may also want to run this entire script under `set -x` and set a trap for `ERR` to exit immediately on failure with some message.